# Mini Toggle Switch Not Working in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Every JS and CSS file linked properly in WordPress. But Mini Toggle Switch not working.
[fn error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFe6Y.png)
What can i do?

i tried many times.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

In minitoggle.js file, I added to the top

```
;(function($){
```

and to the bottom.

```
})(jQuery);
```

The entire Code look like this.

```
;(function($){
      $.fn["minitoggle"] = function(options) {
      options = options || {};
      opts = $.extend({
        on: false
      }, options);
      doToggle = function(toggle) {
        toggle = toggle.find(".minitoggle");
        active = toggle.toggleClass("active").hasClass("active");
        handle = toggle.find(".toggle-handle");
        handlePosition = handle.position()
        offset = (active ? toggle.width() - handle.width() - handlePosition.left * 2 : 0);
        handle.css({
          transform: "translate3d(" + offset + "px,0,0)",
        });
        return toggle.trigger({
          type: "toggle",
          isActive: active
        });
      };
      this.each(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        self.html("<div class=\"minitoggle\"><div class=\"toggle-handle\"></div></div>");
        self.click(function() {
          doToggle(self);
        });
        if (opts["on"]) {
          doToggle(self);
        }
      });
    };
    
    })(jQuery);
```